# Shakespeare's omission of 'as' before 'single' in 'When sorrows come, they come not single spies...'

Tags: shakespeare

When Shakespeare wrote: "When sorrows come, they come not single spies, but in battalions", why didn't he put an "as" before "single spies"?

Comment: Because that's how he wanted it.

Comment: It's a much better title now. Why not tell us where the line is from?

Comment: it's for the syllable count, a nice 466

Comment: @HotLicks - don't bother commenting if you've nothing useful to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sort of context, where the nominal is a secondary subject complement, EME did not require *as* with nominals, just as we still don't require it with adjectivals:

> He came galumphing back.
>   He came home defeated.

Here's a non-Shakespearean example:

> Firſt, [God] comes a *Little-One* : to ſshew, that hee is food for *Little-Ones* ; [...] A *little One* hee comes, from the leaſt of the cities ; *Little*, of Accompt : *Little*, in Appearance ; that we might not be *afraid* to come neere him. [...] And laſtly, he comes a *Little-One* to us, to ſhew, we muſt come, as *Little-Ones*, to him. —Austin, *Devotionis Augustinianae Flamma*, 1635

So Shakespeare might include *as* or omit it; and the meter here calls for omission.

Comment: " ... where the nominal is a secondary subject complement" - what does that mean? And what is EME?

Comment: EME = Early Modern English

Comment: @Peter4075 A "secondary complement" is a non-obligatory complement to the verb. An object complement describes the object of the clause--*He drinks his coffee **black***, where *black* describes *coffee*--and a subject complement describes the subject of the clause--*He drinks his coffee **naked***, where *naked* describes *He*.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly to maintain metre, but perhaps also to make it a metaphor rather than a simile. The metaphor sounds more arrogant, more assertive, which matches Claudius' character.

Comment: I can't agree with this. (1) *As* in this context would not make this a simile--it plays the same role as *in* in *in battalions*; (2) metaphors are not inherently more "arrogant" or "assertive" than similes; (3) Claudius is not particularly "arrogant" or "assertive" in this passage: he is rather shaken by recent events and the current atmosphere.

Comment: I did say 'perhaps' indicating what follows is my interpretation. (1) I do understand that 'as' is a preposition too, but my understanding is C is comparing 'sorrows' to 'spies' in an analogy.  Regarding (2) I made no such generalisation. (3) Open to interpretation. At least we agree that this is for metrical purposes - which is the correct answer. +1 on your response for staying on topic: I've clearly muddied the waters!